# How to proxy to root path with node http-proxy

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, node-http-proxy

I am trying to setup a proxy with an express app to a root path from a specific path in my application:

```
http://my-domain.com/some/route --> http://another-domain:8000/
```

I have tried multiple things per the http-proxy docs but I keep hitting a wall with the paths/routing. I am trying to do this within a logged in express app so that I can utilize my authentication behind the app i'm trying to proxy too. I keep getting an error with the proxy'd app saying the path '/some/route' is not defined...etc.

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host:'localhost',
    port:8000
});
```

I've also tried:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/';
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

proxy.web(req,res, { target: url }, function(e) {
    console.log('proxy.web callback');
    console.log(e);
});
```

The function calls but I end up with an express 404 error...

I would also like to pass in some variables if that is possible so for example:

```
http://my-domain.com/some/route?var1=something&var2=something --> http://another-domain:8000/?var1=something&var2=something
```

But could not figure out if that was possible, I tried setting it on the request since that was being sent into the proxyRequest, but was unable to find them in the second application.

Comment: Don't know. I've already lost a lot of time with `http-proxy`. I'm using now **nginx**. And you could have a look at [Redbird](https://github.com/OptimalBits/redbird). Looks good to me...

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't do this with just `node-http-proxy`.

But it's possible with `http-proxy-middleware` (and you likely use it already):

> <sub>From [comment by @chimurai on github](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/31#issuecomment-143770591):</sub>
>
> You can rewrite paths with the [`pathRewrite` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware#options).
>
> ```
> var options = {
>   target: 'http://test.com',
>   changeOrigin: true,
>   pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''}      // <-- this will remove the /api prefix
> };
>
> server.middleware = proxyMiddleware('/api', options);
> ```

And if you come here because you're using `webpack-dev-server`, note that it also internally uses `http-proxy-middleware`, starting from version `2.0.0-beta` ([see PR](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/359)).

Side note: There is also a node-proxy plugin, [`http-proxy-rules`](https://github.com/donasaur/http-proxy-rules), so you can use this one if you don't want middleware.

Comment: "And if you come here because you're using webpack-dev-server" +1 +1!!!

Comment: @mik01aj  I am fedding up with parse the url in ```app.use('/???')``` in http proxy middleware , could yo uplease give some suggestion on this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64652571/http-proxy-middleware-is-not-created-proxies-in-my-react-app)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I encounter another problem, but needed to solve this problem first. I came up with this code, which worked fine for me ;)

Just use this for "/some/route"

```
.... // your stuff

httpProxy.on('error', function (err, req, res) {
    res.writeHead(500, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.end('some error');
});

app.all( '/some/route/*' , function( req , res ) {

        var url = req.url;
        url = url.slice(11); // to remove "/some/route"

        req.url = url;

        return httpProxy.web(req, res , { target: "http://another-domain:8000" } );

} );
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Any problem will appear If I change the url of req?
I have do this but I don't know if it will get more others problems.
`
ctx.req.url = '/'
ctx.req.originalUrl = '/';
`the target is destination