# http proxy middleware is not created proxies in my react app

Tags: reactjs, http-proxy-middleware

I am implementing http proxy middleware in to  my react app.  I want to proxing qa or dev backend services urls from my local .

Example of my dev login url below

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://dev.sju.uk/auth/login`

my setupProxy.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use('/auth/login' ,createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://dev.sju.uk/auth/login',
    changeOrigin: true,
  })
  );
};
```

I started my app and click the login button and the request got failed with 404 not found error . Not sure why my target is not replacing with my actual `http://localhost:9009/auth/login` uri to  `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://dev.sju.uk/auth/login`.

Also am not getting `proxy created  message in my console` when we do `npm start` as well. I am using webpack dev server not react-scripts . If any changes required on webpack side or am i missing anything badly please let me know. I tried small poc it got worked but that is simple without herokuapp things.

Comment: You using this as proxy? -  https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
In this case that server doesn't know what is your "localhost", that's the reason if fails. Your option would be to start this proxy server locally (or make you server publically available), and you can do that - https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/

Comment: @NikitaChayka  no i did not used  proxy value as ``` cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com``` , mentioned above package.json.

Comment: anyway it might i am missing something here, but i don't quite understand how you expect some external server to know what your "localhost" is

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it :( maybe someone else would be able to help you with this

Comment: @NikitaChayka i modified my question , can you check. It might give proper need

Comment: if i am not mistaken you actually should set proxy in packages.json to http://localhost:9009

Comment: @NikitaChayka i have updated my question clearly where is am stuck can you look plz ,

Comment: What @NikitaChayka has pointed on Nov 2, 2020 at 23:52 in relation to "set proxy in packages.json to localhost:9009" is basically to tell Express to use that as a single Endpoint proxy. This is the simple solution to solve the Cors problem when calling a single API. But, if you need to call 1+ Apis you need to use another kind of proxy like http-proxy-middleware that's the one asked in this question.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to understand how the http-proxy-middleware works.

Look at the following diagram from the http-proxy-middleware [Docs](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-middleware)

```
     foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |           |            |            |        |
   scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
```

For simple configurations, any request that your front-end does calling an API get observed by a matching pattern on the path section of the above diagram and overwritten with your target configuration, to be exposed in the header of the request as a different URL. This also help you in the development phase locally to avoid the CORS blocking mechanism of the browsers.

Example:
Let's imagine we need to call from our front-end exposed at http://localhost:3000 to an endpoint located at https://localhost:7005/api/WeatherForecast

This type of calls will be blocked in all browsers by CORS.

So, with the following config, you will be able to bypass the cors problem.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const context = [
    "/api",
];

module.exports = function (app) {

    const webApiProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context[0], {
        target: 'https://localhost:7005',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        headers: {
            Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
        },
        logLevel: 'debug'
    });

    app.use(webApiProxy);
};
```

With this, any request made from http://localhost:3000 will be intercepted by the proxy-middleware and if it finds a /api in some part of the path will be changed to https://localhost:7005/api and also concatenate the rest of your original path following the /api.

So finally, your front-end will be asking things from http://localhost:3000 but all the request will arrive to https://localhost:7005 as if they were request by https://localhost:7005 and this will fix the Cors problem coz your requesting and responding from the same origin.

I Guess your can fix your problem by writting your config this way:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use('/auth/login' ,createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'https://dev.sju.uk/auth/login',
    changeOrigin: true,
    headers: {
       Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    },
  })
  );
};
```

Bare in mind, this libray not only can help you with the CORS problem but also to perform hundred of things for any request/response like change arguments from the body, add things to the body, add headers, perform operations before the request aka logging what's requested, perform operations on the response aka logging again what has returned, etc, etc.

Hope this will help to resolve your issue!